# Asp.net MVC 3 not working with Ninject after upgrade from MVC 2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, caching, ninject

I have a web application which was using **Asp.net MVC2**. I Upgraded it to **MVC 3** and now I found that **OutputCache** feature is not working any-more. I created a simple Test action as shown below.

```
 [OutputCache(Duration = 1000000, VaryByParam = "none")]
 public virtual ActionResult CacheTest(string name)
  {
     string message = string.Format("{0}: Time is {1}", name, DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
     ViewData.Add("Message", message);
     return View();
  }
```

This always gives the **current time** which shows that it is **not cached**. Am I missing something here?

**More Info:** If i create a new Mvc3 app it works fine. Its only in the upgraded app that I have this issue.

**Update:** I am also using Ninject. If I stop using Ninject OutputCache starts working.

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}.aspx/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            RegisterDependencyResolver();

            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }

        protected void RegisterDependencyResolver()
        {
            var kernel = CreateKernel();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
        }

        protected IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            return new StandardKernel();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Weird, I am unable to reproduce the problem. The cache works for me.

Comment: If i create a new Mvc3 app it works fine. Its only in the upgraded app that I have this issue.

Comment: This all makes no sense. For me, this a) can't be reprod b) just makes no sense - Ninject just ahs nothign to do with `OutputCacheAttribute` so there must just be something messed up like having multiple versions of Ninject or MVC in play. See also https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ninject/NtsBWNS4MJs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct and recommended way to use Ninject in ASP.NET MVC 3 is the following:

1. Install the `ninject.mvc3` NuGet package. This will ensure that you get the latest version compatible with ASP.NET MVC 3.
2. Once installed this will add a `App_Start/NinjectMVC3.cs` file to your project and it is inside the `RegisterServices` method that you will register your Ninject modules:

   ```
   private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
   {
       var modules = new INinjectModule[]
       {
           // your modules here
       };
       kernel.Load(modules);
   }
   ```
3. Remove all Ninject specific code from your Global.asax including any `NinjectDependencyResolver`.

Try following those steps and maybe your problem will get fixed.